# c++ dll via Win runtime component in c# UWP app works for Arm but not for x86/x64

Tags: c++, dll, windows-runtime, uwp, udp

I need to call win32 socket apis from C# UWP app for Windows10(same app to run on desktop and mobile) as win10 sock library has some issues
Environment - VS2015 Update 3.

I created project structure as explaind  [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisbarker/2014/10/08/consuming-a-c-library-project-from-a-windows-phone-store-app/).
So the calling is as follows..

C# UWP app -> C++ WindowsRuntimeComponent -> Universal dll(c++) (having code from c++ win32 dll)

In dll I simply create a UDP server and wait for udp packets at recvfrom(.....)

This works fine when I run the app on Win 10 Mobile device (ARM) but does not work when architecture selected is x86 or x64. I donot recive any udp packet forx64/x86 in recvfrom() while bind() is successful.

How is it that same code works for ARM and not for x64/x86. What could be the issue.

Comment: Are you by any chance running code on the same machine in those cases?

Comment: @Sunius - Sorry, I did not exactly get the question.. By 'those cases' I guess , you mean x86/x64 ..right?  Forx64 -  I am executing it in VS2015 with Debug+x64 + Local Machine and Debug+x64+Simulator. In both cases after behaviour is same...no result after calling recvfrom().

Comment: By the way my desktop shows -> Win10 Enterprise, Version 1511, OS build 10586.873,64 bit OS ...( but I guess this should not have any adverse impact on issue faced )

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store applications cannot listen on sockets or receive data from UDP connections if both ends of the socket are on the same machine. Run the server and your application on separate machines.

Comment: Client and server are running on separate machines.

Comment: How can dll code be debugged, the breakpoints inserted are not active in dll code. Any special steps to follow?

Comment: Make sure your debugger is set to native or mixed mode debugging if your app is managed. Other than that, make sure the PDB for it is loaded in VS modules window.

Answer (score 0):

A security patch was waiting to install on the clinet machine (Win 7 OS) was the reason for server waiting in recvfrom() call...

After the patch was installed and system restarted, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem. The recvfrom function has not received packets from the local network. The problem was resolved by adding the privateNetworkClientServer capability to the application manifest (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).